Como puedo saber el ultimo día laborable del mes actual, sin contemplar sábado o domingo en SQL Server?
Con la función EOMONTH() puedo obtener el ultimo día, pero si ese último día es domingo y no se trabaja? entonces en ese caso debería de traerme como resultado el viernes que fue el último día laborable de ese mes.
SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE()) FROM TABLA1

Tal vez esta pregunta esté relacionada.

¿Y vas a contar días festivos?

Solo es saber el ultimo día laborable del mes actual, que sean de lunes a viernes.

No es para una aplicación, es para un visuals en PBI, pero necesito tenerlo en la DB, para poder hacer otros tipos de análisis.

Para obtener el viernes en vez de sábado y domingo (que no es lo mismo que el último día laboral), puedes usar esta expresión. Esta expresión funciona sin importar la configuración de idioma o fecha que tengas en tu base de datos.
Lo que hace es identificar el sábado y domingo al tomar la diferencia entre una fecha, en este caso EOMONTH( GETDATE()) y tomar el residuo de las semanas completas al compararla con la fecha cero (1900-01-01). Así se puede identificar si hay que restarle un día, dos o ninguno.
SELECT DATEADD( DD, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, 0, EOMONTH( GETDATE())) % 7 = 5 THEN - 1
                         WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, 0, EOMONTH( GETDATE())) % 7 = 6 THEN - 2
                         ELSE 0 END, EOMONTH( GETDATE()))


Muchas gracias, lo hice de otro metodo mucho mas largo, pero con este simple codigo me funciona nitido, gracias mil.

@William, bienvenido, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Si este código te ha funcionado, lo propio sería votar a favor y marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Encontrarás más información en ¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?
